# Send response multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, socket.io

I have a little problem.

I have a node application on a server, that serves a website as control panel for a client based application.

Example:

1. You click a link on the site
2. A http request triggers the server to send a command via socket to the client
3. The client executes this command
4. The client sends the output of the command back to the server (socket)

That works fine, on time. The second time the server crashes because the header is already sent.

```js
//Comand comes in
app.get('/create/:id/:package', function (req, res) {
    if (io.sockets.connected[req.params.id]) {
        //Command is sent to client
        io.sockets.connected[req.params.id].emit('control', {type: 'create', packageName: req.params.package});
        //Output is coming back
        socket.on('createOutput', function (data) {
            //Response sent back to http request (works once)
            res.send(data);
        });
    }
});
```

Is there any way to work around this behavior?

Comment: Each time your `app.get()` handler is called, you add yet another `socket.on()` event handler so they will accumulate.

Comment: This architecture (even the fix proposed by Andrei) assumes that every `.emit('control')` will be followed by receiving a `'createOutput'` message back from the same socket which is not always guaranteed to be true (there could be errors somewhere).  This whole architecture of how this works is pretty bizarre. You're essentially asking the client who sent the request to give you the data for the response.  Why in the world would you architect things that way. If the client knows the response, then it should get the data from itself rather than asking the server to ask it to then give it back.

Comment: I know the aproach is a little strange. The example has a failure, i found later. The listener on createOutput must sit on io.sockets.connected[req.params.id]. That way the socket is properly defined because it sends its own id in the process.

Comment: The client actually knows the response, but the website rendered by the server must show it. Its a control application, that must be able to send commands to connected clients and each client gets its own dynamic version of the control panel. Its controlling a build process where the client sends data to another client, to build an app. For company security reasons, the build process can't run on the first client and this client can't communicate directly to the build-client. So the server transfers the data, handles the communication and hosts the control panel and logging funtions.

Comment: its a small part of a semi-automatic build process in a nearly ridiculous security environment. Thats where the architecture is comming from.

Answer (score 1):

You can send the data only once with `socket.once`:

```
socket.once('createOutput', function (data) {
        //Response sent back to http request (works once)
        res.send(data);
    })
```